In the shell, repeated reading is due to buffer overflow or memory overflow issues?
When I run the code, I find it will call the function lsh_read_line() twice.However, according to the logic of the program, it will only call the function once.
In the shell, repeated reading is due to buffer overflow or memory overflow issues?
Output
(base) root@autodl-container-b9b842b3fc-72c7a685:/home/lsh# ./lsh

1
lsh: No such file or directory
49 10 49 10 >

Code
/***************************************************************************//**

  @file         main.c

  @author       Stephen Brennan

  @date         Thursday,  8 January 2015

  @brief        LSH (Libstephen SHell)

*******************************************************************************/

#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
  Function Declarations for builtin shell commands:
 */
int lsh_cd(char **args);
int lsh_help(char **args);
int lsh_exit(char **args);

/*
  List of builtin commands, followed by their corresponding functions.
 */
char *builtin_str[] = {
  "cd",
  "help",
  "exit"
};

int (*builtin_func[]) (char **) = {
  &lsh_cd,
  &lsh_help,
  &lsh_exit
};

int lsh_num_builtins() {
  return sizeof(builtin_str) / sizeof(char *);
}

/*
  Builtin function implementations.
*/

/**
   @brief Builtin command: change directory.
   @param args List of args.  args[0] is "cd".  args[1] is the directory.
   @return Always returns 1, to continue executing.
 */
int lsh_cd(char **args)
{
  if (args[1] == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "lsh: expected argument to \"cd\"\n");
  } else {
    if (chdir(args[1]) != 0) {
      perror("lsh");
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

/**
   @brief Builtin command: print help.
   @param args List of args.  Not examined.
   @return Always returns 1, to continue executing.
 */
int lsh_help(char **args)
{
  int i;
  printf("Stephen Brennan's LSH\n");
  printf("Type program names and arguments, and hit enter.\n");
  printf("The following are built in:\n");

  for (i = 0; i < lsh_num_builtins(); i++) {
    printf("  %s\n", builtin_str[i]);
  }

  printf("Use the man command for information on other programs.\n");
  return 1;
}

/**
   @brief Builtin command: exit.
   @param args List of args.  Not examined.
   @return Always returns 0, to terminate execution.
 */
int lsh_exit(char **args)
{
  return 0;
}

/**
  @brief Launch a program and wait for it to terminate.
  @param args Null terminated list of arguments (including program).
  @return Always returns 1, to continue execution.
 */
int lsh_launch(char **args)
{
  pid_t pid;
  int status;

  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    // Child process
    if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) {
      perror("lsh");
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else if (pid < 0) {
    // Error forking
    perror("lsh");
  } else {
    // Parent process
    do {
      waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
    } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
  }

  return 1;
}

/**
   @brief Execute shell built-in or launch program.
   @param args Null terminated list of arguments.
   @return 1 if the shell should continue running, 0 if it should terminate
 */
int lsh_execute(char **args)
{
  int i;

  if (args[0] == NULL) {
    // An empty command was entered.
    return 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < lsh_num_builtins(); i++) {
    if (strcmp(args[0], builtin_str[i]) == 0) {
      return (*builtin_func[i])(args);
    }
  }

  return lsh_launch(args);

}

/**
   @brief Read a line of input from stdin.
   @return The line from stdin.
 */
char *lsh_read_line(void)
{
#ifdef LSH_USE_STD_GETLINE
  char *line = NULL;
  ssize_t bufsize = 0; // have getline allocate a buffer for us
  if (getline(&line, &bufsize, stdin) == -1) {
    if (feof(stdin)) {
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  // We received an EOF
    } else  {
      perror("lsh: getline\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }
  return line;
#else
#define LSH_RL_BUFSIZE 1024
  int bufsize = LSH_RL_BUFSIZE;
  int position = 0;
  char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * bufsize);
  int c;

  if (!buffer) {
    fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (1) {
    // Read a character
    c = getchar();
    printf("%d ", c);

    if (c == EOF) {
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else if (c == '\n') {
      buffer[position] = '\0';
      return buffer;
    } else {
      buffer[position] = c;
    }
    position++;

    // If we have exceeded the buffer, reallocate.
    if (position >= bufsize) {
      bufsize += LSH_RL_BUFSIZE;
      buffer = realloc(buffer, bufsize);
      if (!buffer) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }

  // while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { /* 清空缓冲区 */ }
  }


#endif
}

#define LSH_TOK_BUFSIZE 64
#define LSH_TOK_DELIM " \t\r\n\a"
/**
   @brief Split a line into tokens (very naively).
   @param line The line.
   @return Null-terminated array of tokens.
 */
char **lsh_split_line(char *line)
{
  int bufsize = LSH_TOK_BUFSIZE, position = 0;
  char **tokens = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char*));
  char *token, **tokens_backup;

  if (!tokens) {
    fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  token = strtok(line, LSH_TOK_DELIM);
  while (token != NULL) {
    tokens[position] = token;
    position++;

    if (position >= bufsize) {
      bufsize += LSH_TOK_BUFSIZE;
      tokens_backup = tokens;
      tokens = realloc(tokens, bufsize * sizeof(char*));
      if (!tokens) {
        free(tokens_backup);
        fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }

    token = strtok(NULL, LSH_TOK_DELIM);
  }
  tokens[position] = NULL;
  return tokens;
}

/**
   @brief Loop getting input and executing it.
 */
void lsh_loop(void)
{
  char *line;
  char **args;
  int status;

  do {
    printf("> ");
    line = lsh_read_line();

    args = lsh_split_line(line);

    status = lsh_execute(args);
    

    free(line);
    
    free(args);
    

  } while (status);
}

/**
   @brief Main entry point.
   @param argc Argument count.
   @param argv Argument vector.
   @return status code
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Load config files, if any.

  // Run command loop.
  lsh_loop();

  // Perform any shutdown/cleanup.

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}



When I comment out this line of code status = lsh_execute(args), the output becomes normal.It's possible that the issue is related to the creation of child processes.

In lsh_read_line you print each character as an integer which does not make much sense. It would be better to print the tokens that you are sending to the command, so you can see what is happening. Also you can run this code without the call to fork to make it slightly simpler.

Yes, simply replacing printf("%d ", c); with putchar (c); makes your shell make more sense. Then incorporating the fix Eric points out below will eliminate your double-buffer on fork() problem.

I cannot reproduce your error, have you modified the submitted code.  But that smells to not flushing the buffers prior to call fork().

The output to your terminal is line buffered. This means that, when a printf or other write operation to standard output is executed, the output is not immediately sent to the terminal. Instead, it is held in a buffer inside the program. The buffered data is sent to the terminal when the buffer is full, when the program explicitly requests a flush, or when input is solicited on an interactive device. A flush is also performed when a program exits normally. This buffering is done for efficiency; it uses less system resources for the program to send many characters at once instead of sending a few characters each time a printf is performed.
When your program calls fork, the entire process is duplicated, including the buffer. Later, each process prints the contents of the buffer, resulting in the buffer contents being printed twice.
To avoid that, execute fflush(NULL); immediately before the fork. This will write the buffer contents to the terminal, emptying the buffer. Then the contents will not be duplicated by the fork, so only one copy will be printed.
